# Disabled form fields not submitting data

Tags: html, css, forms, disabled-input

Is there any way (with a attribute flag or something like that) to enable form fields that are disabled to submit data?

Or, if that's not possible, is there any way to block fields from editing with css or any other attribute than disabled without hiding them?

My special case at the moment is an identifier for a data-set that should be shown in the form (uneditable) - if there is no better solution I think i'll use a hidden field in addition to the disabled one to hold the actual value with the disabled one showing it.

Comment: Why not use "readonly" instead of "disabled"?

Comment: Duplicate the field in question. have a input with type hidden filled with the value you need to submit. Since you have your disabled field it doesn't change. When you fill one fill both.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77931212/548473

Answer (score 58):

As it was already mentioned: `READONLY` does not work for `<input type='checkbox'>` and `<select>...</select>`.

If you have a `Form` with disabled checkboxes / selects AND need them to be submitted, you can use jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    $(':disabled').each(function(e) {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    })
});
```

This code removes the `disabled` attribute from all elements on submit.

Comment: Bro ... I didn't realise this was an issue till completing a whole page. So much javascript. Then I moved onto the backend and .... none of them were posting through. Thanks a lot for this answer!

Comment: This script is concise and amazing, thank you so much.  Great for work in MVC/Razor Pages

Comment: Nice solution, the best I saw for MVC. Thx.

Comment: if you want to only disable checkboxes then change the `$(':disabled')` to `$('input[type="checkbox"]:disabled')`

Comment: Or you can also simply add a hidden field

Answer (score 24):

Use the CSS pointer-events:none on fields you want to "disable" (possibly together with a greyed background) which allows the POST action, like:

```
<input type="text" class="disable">

.disable{
pointer-events:none;
background:grey;
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Wouldn't recommend to use this, as it is heavily browser dependent.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, and pointer-events is now almost universally supported:  https://caniuse.com/?search=pointer-events

Comment: User is still able to navigate to the input via keyboard

Answer (score 6):

We can also use the readonly only with below attributes -

readonly onclick='return false;'

This is because if we will only use the readonly then radio buttons will be editable. To avoid this situation we can use readonly with above combination. It will restrict the editing and element's values will also passed during form submission.

Comment: Use of `readonly` instead of `disabled` attribute to keep `<input>` data is such an elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

add CSS or class to the input element which works in select and text tags like

*style="pointer-events: none;background-color:#E9ECEF"*