# How to get an Id value from association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At this time I need to get and id value from an association
Because I create a new note, but i can assign this note to whoever i want, then I have it this way

```
<%= f.association :user,
        :label      => false,
        :selected   => current_user.id,
        :required   => true,
        :input_html => {
            :class      => 'span4', 
            :disabled   => true, 
            :style      => "float:right", 
            :id         => "usuario"} %>
```

And the controller create method is this way

```
 def create
    @note = Note.new(note_params)
    @note.user_id = params[:user]
    render :action => :new unless @note.save
end
```

But when I press the submit button everything save unless the value for the column :user_id

I have tried with params[:user_id] but it doesn't work

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to remove the attribute `disabled` from your field, a disabled field isn't sended by your form (look at [Disabled form fields not submitting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925716/disabled-form-fields-not-submitting-data)).

And, your user_id should be placed in something like `params[:note][:user_id]`, take a look at server log and search for `user_id` right after you send a POST to server, there be something like:

```
Started POST "/note" for ::1 at 2013-07-18 15:22:34 +0000
Processing by NoteController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"note"=>{..., "user_id"=>"1", ...}}
```

Comment: That's what the app put into the log: Started POST "/notes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 09:43:26 -0500
Processing by NotesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "note"=>{"name"=>"asdasd", "descripcion"=>"asdasdasdasd", "estado"=>"false", "fecha_limite"=>"2013-07-19", "prioridad"=>"2", "solicita"=>"asdasdasdasd"}, "commit"=>"Guardar"}

Comment: :D :D Man thank you so much, now that's working as I want, i didn't know that about disabled field