# html disabled input text post form

Tags: php, html, post, input

That's my test code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['Est1'])) echo 'Est1 : ' . $_POST['Est1'] . '<br>';
    if(isset($_POST['Est2'])) echo 'Est2 : ' . $_POST['Est2'] . '<br>';
    if(isset($_POST['Est3'])) echo 'Est3 : ' . $_POST['Est3'] . '<br>';
    if(isset($_POST['Est4'])) echo 'Est4 : ' . $_POST['Est4'] . '<br>';
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Est1" id="Val1" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="Est2" id="Val2" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="Est3" id="Val3" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="Est4" id="Val4" value="test" disabled="disabled"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In this form, when I send the value of the input Est4 is never returned:
isset($_POST['Est4']) return false!

Why ?

Comment: disabled inputs don't post their values

Comment: If you want it to be able to be read but not changed and still posted use the `readonly` attribute

Comment: Disabled inputs do not post their values, use javascript to undisable it before sending or use the readonly attribute.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77931212/548473

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your disabled by readonly:

```
<input type="text" name="Est4" id="Val4" value="test" readonly/>
```