# PHP not retrieving JQuery updated input value

Tags: php, jquery

I am using JQuery to readily update an input field with a total number of hours that is generated by using datetimepicker to compare two dates selected by the user. My problem is after the input field `#numberOfHours` is updated with the result from this function:

```
$('#startForm').keyup(function () {
          var start_actual_time = $('#datetimepicker').val();

          var end_actual_time = $('#datetimepicker2').val();

          $hourlyRate = $('#hourlyRate').val();
          $fixedPrice = $('#fixedRate').val();

            //CALCULATE TIME BETWEEN TWO DATES
          start_actual_time = new Date(start_actual_time);
          end_actual_time = new Date(end_actual_time);

          var diff = end_actual_time - start_actual_time;

          var diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
          var HH = Math.floor(diffSeconds / 3600);
          var MM = Math.floor(diffSeconds % 3600) / 60;

          var formatted = ((HH < 10) ? ("0" + HH) : HH) + "." + ((MM < 10) ? ("0" + MM) : MM);

          $totalHours = formatted;

          $('#numberOfHours').val($totalHours); //this is getting updated but not passed on to the PHP insert page.

      });

});
```

The result is not being passed to my PHP page, and instead being sent as not set. Let's say the users total hours were updated on the screen to 500 before submitting the form, I would expect this to return 500 but instead is returning 1.

```
$total_hours = isset($_POST["numberOfHours"]) ? $_POST["numberOfHours"] : '1';
```

numberOfHours html input:

```
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numberOfHours" id="numberOfHours" value="0" disabled="disabled" />
```

Could someone shed some light on what is happening behind the scenes that is forcing the value to not be passed along

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the html property **name** of your input to **numberOfHours**?

Comment: @JSelser Yes, I added the relevant html above

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do this

```
  $('#numberOfHours').empty();
  $('#numberOfHours').val($totalHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this stack post: [html disabled input text post form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701089/html-disabled-input-text-post-form)

readonly solves the problem here, as it was getting sent as not set because of the disabled property.

Comment: Flagged question for closing

Comment: Yep, **disabled** won't send your stuff