# PHP script Issue when disabled form

Tags: php

Here I have form:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$username   = $_POST[username];
$email  = $_POST[email];
$domain     = $_POST[domain];
$pass   = $_POST[pass];
$package    = $_POST[package];
}

    <form action="/apiclass/code/da_create_user2.php" method="post" name="form_create_domain" id="form_create_domain">
          Nazwa domeny<input name="domain" type="text" id="domain"><br />
          User server<input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $user_details['username']; ?><?php echo "a02"; ?>"><br />
          Email<input name="email" type="text" id="email"  value="<?php echo $user_details['email']; ?>"><br />
          Haslo<input name="pass" type="password" id="pass"><br />
          Pakiet<input name="package" type="text" id="package"  value="newpackakge"><br />
      <p align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Install shop">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset Form">
    </p>
    </form>
```

this form running php script in:

```
/apiclass/code/da_create_user2.php
```

example:

`<input name="username"` is variable in file `da_create_user2.php $username`

I need to set it, so that the user cannot change the text username.

I try add to form: `disable` or `readonly` also I try add `.js` code

```
document.getElementById('username').disabled = true;
```

When I set it up like this and try to submit the form, it gets an error as if that value was not passed to the PHP script.  The script then believes that I'm sending an empty value. How to solve it?

Comment: `it gets an error` means the PHP throws a notice/warning or you get a browser/console error? If the error is on the next page please include the code related to the error and the code. A `disable`d element wont send, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989845/how-do-i-post-disabled-input

Comment: Really Thanks Dear! This tip with  only hidden  wihout  "" help me and working now!