# Access disabled field with symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin

i have a probleme with the disabled form field in symfony.

Some of the field i display are filled with an event(a click on a checkbox) and once filled become disabled so they wont be editable.

The probleme is that i can't find the value that was inserted in the field once they go disabled symfony just ignore everything does someone have an idea ?

Thank you for reading

Comment: the problem is not in symfony but in html specification. Disabled inputs have no value after a form submit. You should use rather readonly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabled form fields not submitting data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925716/disabled-form-fields-not-submitting-data)

Comment: When the field is disabled in the formbuilder and not in the (twig) template then Symfony uses the prefill data to fill the form element.

Answer (score 2):

When you make a field disabled, it won't get submitted. So can you use readonly attribute instead of that. Use data attribute to check the field by default.

```
$form->add('name','choice',
    'choices' => array("1" => "A") ,
    'multiple' => 'multiple' ,
    'data'=>array(1),
    'disabled'=>true,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not about Symfony, it's about HTML Forms.

Disabled form fields won't get sumbitted. So Symfony can't see any data. Try the readonly attribute.

See: [Disabled form fields not submitting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925716/disabled-form-fields-not-submitting-data)