# PHP - Cannot access POST value from an HTML form submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, mariadb

I am receiving this error (4 times) when attempting to submit a form table:

> Notice: Undefined index: accountid in php/ChartOfAccountsInclude.php on >line 106

This is line 106 in my code

```
$account_id = $_POST["accountid"][$i];
```

I am attempting to load in table data from a local database. Then I allow the user access to certain fields to change the values. Once they are done they press the button to submit and that is when I get the above error. There are currently four accounts in the database which means each time my code is looping through the POST value it is failing to retrieve the accountid. I have pasted the relevant code below:

User Page *ChartOfAccounts.php*

```
<?php
    include("view/SiteHeader.php");
    include('php/ChartOfAccountsInclude.php');
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chart of Accounts</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <br/>
        <h2>Chart of Accounts</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
                <?php retrieveChart() ;?>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <button type="submit" name="submitMods" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Submit Account Modifications</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php if($submit_err) : ?>
            <?php generateError('warning', 'Account could not be updated.') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP Include *ChartOfAccountsInclude.php*

```
<?php
    include_once('php/session.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $submit_err = FALSE;
    $submitaccount_err = FALSE;

    function retrieveChart() {
        global $db;
        $funcSQL = "SELECT * FROM Accounts";
        $funcResult = mysqli_query($db,$funcSQL);

        echo '<table border="1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Account ID</th>
            <th>Account Name</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Term</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($funcResult))
        {
            $current = $longterm = $active = $inactive = $debi = $credit = $asset = $expense = $liability = $equity = $revenue = "";
            $curusr = $row['user_id'];
            $getUsernameSQL = "SELECT username FROM User_accounts WHERE user_id = $curusr";
            $usernameResult = mysqli_query($db,$getUsernameSQL);
            $usernameRow = mysqli_fetch_array($usernameResult);

            switch ($row['term']) {
                case 'Current':
                    $current = "selected = \"selected\"";
                    break;
                case 'Long Term':
                    $longterm = "selected = \"selected\"";
                    break;
            }
            switch ($row['account_status']) {
                case 'Active':
                    $active = "selected = \"selected\"";
                    break;
                case 'Inactive':
                    $inactive = "selected = \"selected\"";
                    break;
            }
            switch ($row['type']) {
                case 'Asset':
                    $asset = "selected = \"selected\"";
                    break;
                case 'Expense':
                    $expense = "selected = \"selected\"";
                    break;
                case 'Liability':
                    $liability = "selected = \"selected\"";
                    break;
                case 'Equity':
                    $equity = "selected = \"selected\"";
                    break;
                case 'Revenue':
                    $revenue = "selected = \"selected\"";
                    break;
            }

            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td> <input name="accountid[]" disabled value="' . $row['account_id'] . '"> </td>';
                echo '<td> <input name="accountname[]" value="' . $row['account_name'] . '"> </td>';
                echo '<td> <input name="datecreated[]" disabled value="' . $row['date_created'] . '"> </td>';
                echo '<td> 
                        <select name="type[]">
                            <option '.$asset.'>Asset</option>
                            <option '.$expense.'>Expense</option>
                            <option '.$liability.'>Liability</option>
                            <option '.$equity.'>Equity</option>
                            <option '.$revenue.'>Revenue</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>';
                echo '<td> 
                        <select name="term[]">
                            <option '.$current.'>Current</option>
                            <option '.$longterm.'>Long Term</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>';
                echo '<td> 
                        <select name="accountstatus[]" value="' . $row['account_status'] . '">
                            <option '.$active.'>Active</option>
                            <option '.$inactive.'>Inactive</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>';
                echo '<td>
                        <input name="user_id[]" disabled value="' . $usernameRow['username'] . '">
                    </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        } 
        echo '</table>';
    }

    if( isset($_POST['submitMods']) ) {
        $i = 0;

        while($i < $count) {
            $account_id = $_POST["accountid"][$i];
            $account_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['accountname'][$i]);
            $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['type'][$i]);
            $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['term'][$i]);
            $account_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['accountstatus'][$i]);

            $updateAccountsql = "
                UPDATE Accounts
                SET
                    account_id = '$account_id',
                    account_name = '$account_name',
                    type = '$type',
                    term = '$term',
                    account_status = '$account_status'
                WHERE account_id = '$account_id'";

            if($account_name == "") {
                $submit_err = TRUE;
            } else {
                $updateResult = mysqli_query($db,$updateAccountsql);
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if(!$submit_err) {
            //header("Location: ChartOfAccounts.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Disabled value will not submitted in form

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request

Comment: change disabled to hidden

Comment: I did not realize that. Thank you! readonly attribute is what I was actually after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **HTML Elements with Disabled attribute are not posted** or you can say their values are not submitted.

Your input element is as below so it will not post any value.

```
<input name="accountid[]" value="' . $row['account_id'] . '" disabled />
```

**Disabled controls Limitations:**

- it will not receive focus.
- it will be skipped in tabbing navigation.
- It cannot be successfully posted.

So **if you dont want let user edit that input and if it is not neccessary to show that input to users then you can try `input type="hidden"`** as below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="accountid[]" value="' . $row['account_id'] . '" />
```

Or **If you want to show the id to user but not want to let them edit then you can use readonly attribute in your case**, by readonly attribute you will be able to post your field's data, see below for example:

```
<input type="text" name="accountid[]" value="' . $row['account_id'] . '" readonly />
```

**Read-only elements**

- can receive focus but cannot be modified by the user.
- it will included in tabbing navigation.
- it will be successfully posted.
- doesn't work on checkboxes and select tags

[Reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925716/disabled-form-fields-not-submitting-data/30774689#30774689)

Answer (score 1):

Change below line

```
<input name="user_id[]" disabled value="' . $usernameRow['username'] . '">
```

to

```
<input name="user_id[]" type="hidden" value="' . $usernameRow['username'] . '">
```

Answer (score 1):

Because  accountid is disabled field so it do not submitted and not exist in $_POST variable so you need to replace your textbox with hidden field

Answer (score 0):

**Removed `disabled` from the input fields**

replace

```
echo '<td> <input name="accountid[]" disabled value="' . $row['account_id'] . '"> </td>';
echo '<td> <input name="accountname[]" value="' . $row['account_name'] . '"> </td>';
echo '<td> <input name="datecreated[]" disabled value="' . $row['date_created'] . '"> </td>';
```

with

```
echo '<td> <input name="accountid[]" value="' . $row['account_id'] . '"> </td>';
echo '<td> <input name="accountname[]" value="' . $row['account_name'] . '"> </td>';
echo '<td> <input name="datecreated[]" value="' . $row['date_created'] . '"> </td>';
```

in case if you don't allow people to edit the fields you could use `readonly` in place of `disabled`.