# How to send data of disabled HTML input field of the form to another page through PHP superglobals?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, superglobals

```
<form action="../../Controllers/add-service-action.php" method="GET">
        <label for="service_id">Service Id: </label>
        <input type="text" name="service_id" disabled value="<?php echo generateServiceId(); ?>">
        <br><br>
        <label for="service_name">Service Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="service_name" id="service_name">
        <br><br>
        <label for="service_price">Service Price:</label>
        <input type="text" name="service_price" id="service_price">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Service">
</form>
```

Here, **service_id** is disabled. I am not getting data of **service_id** in **add-service-action.php** page. How can I get thatg?g

Comment: 1.) since it's id so why disclose it, make it hidden. 2) if you want to show it then use CSS to make it disabled rather than using `disabled`. here is the link for your help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925716/disabled-form-fields-not-submitting-data

Comment: why you want to disable field ?