# Can one disable an input field by pure css?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

Like with attribute `disable` on the `<input>` html tag.

I'm not interested in the effects of disabling, like not being included in a POST of the form, and the styling could of course be redone in css, if it should just *look* disabled. (And my input field is a submit button, so disabling from POST is irrelevant.)

I just need it to be unclickable and to look disabled.

Is that possible in pure css without adding the attribute on the html tag?

Comment: Why with CSS and not `disabled` or `readonly` attributes? I'm curious to know of a legit case of why it makes sense to subvert standards and avoid using the html attributes that do exactly what you want.

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to put a div over the top of the button, and then show or hide that div with a transparency of 0.01, i think that would make the button unclickable. and you could alter that divs display property to block/none depending on the status of the button

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable form fields using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963099/how-do-i-disable-form-fields-using-css) - if you don't mind users using tab hacks to reach the input field, the accepted answer works, otherwise IMO that answer sucks.

Comment: I agree. It is not possible I see, and workarounds are horrible, so I may live with using an extra JS line in my code to add that tag. To bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot disable the **functionality** of it via just CSS (since it is there just for **styling** purposes), though you can make it **appear** greyed out like a disabled button using CSS. To make it disabled in terms of functionality, you will have to resort to **JavaScript**.

---

With CSS all you can do is to style your button greyed out via CSS and then create another element over it making its `z-index` higher, setting `position` and `opactiy` to fully transparent. This would mean your actual element is enabled but one will not be able to click it because of element over it with full transparency.

---

Another solution is to just add `pointer-events: none;` to the style of the dom element, should work on most of the browsers.

Comment: Yea okay, it is not possible. Thanks for the answers to both of you.

Comment: @Steeven: There is one way if it would fit your needs, see my last para :)

Comment: Seems like if it requires editing HTML (adding another element), might as well just use the `disabled` attribute and not bother to use unstable hacks. Too bad `:after/:before` doesn't work on inputs.

Answer (score 4):

> you can do in the below manner...

```css
.input-disable {
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

input[type=text] {
  height: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Normal field">
<input type="text" class="input-disable" tabindex="-1" value="disabled field">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add the following CSS which will disable any pointer events. this will also disable hover, focus etc.

```
.style { 
   pointer-events: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it look like disabled, but you cannot prevent it to be clickable with just CSS. An horrible hack would be to overlay a div or some other element, then the button wouldn't be clickable.