# Disable html input element by applying custom css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to disable my all input element of a div by applying my custom css class.
but i could not find any css attribute which can disable an input element.
currently what am i doing

```
  $('#div_sercvice_detail :input').attr('disabled', true);
 $('#retention_interval_div :input').addClass("disabled");
```

which can disable all input element of div with css attr but i want to apply my custom class for disable all input with some extra css attributes

```
 $('#retention_interval_div :input').addClass("disabled");
```

class

```
.disabled{
color : darkGray;
font-style: italic;
/*property for disable input element like*/
/*disabled:true; */
}
```

any suggestion for doing this with jquery without using .attr('disabled', true);?

Comment: Well, `.prop('disabled',true)` is how you _should_ do it with the current version of jQuery - which meets your request for a way to avoid the `.attr()` method.

Comment: +1 for the .prop('disabled', true)

Comment: There is no CSS property to specify `disabled`. jQuery's `.prop()` is the better method. Though I'm assuming you want to avoid that as well as `attr()`. May I ask why?

Comment: You can't disable an element with just CSS, but you CAN accept an answer to each of the 8 previous questions you've posted here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable form fields using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963099/how-do-i-disable-form-fields-using-css)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to disable an element with just CSS, but you can create a style that will be applied to disabled elements:

```
<style>
#retention_interval_div​​ input[type="text"]:disabled { 
    color : darkGray;
    font-style: italic;
}​
</style>
```

Then in your code you just have to say:

```
 $('#retention_interval_div :input').prop("disabled", true);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/DhgMq/

(Of course, the `:disabled` CSS selector isn't supported in old browsers.)

Note that if you're using jQuery version >= 1.6 you should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to change the disabled state.

The code you showed is not disabling the same elements that it applies the class to - the selectors are different. If that's just a typo then you can simplify it to one line:

```
$('#retention_interval_div :input').addClass("disabled").attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use following css to practically disable the input:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score 4):

Using normal CSS

```
.disabled{
    opacity: 0.6;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. CSS can't disable an input element. CSS is for styling only, it can't do anything else. Also, input will only work with input, don't forget select, textarea, password

Comment: The [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) basically selects _all_ form controls, not just `<input type="text">`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things, so why not wrap them in a single function? You could even create a little plugin to do this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.disableInput = function () {
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).prop('disabled');
            $(this).addClass('disabled', true);            
        });

    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
$('#myInput').disableInput();
```

...and even chain it with other stuff, like this:

```
$('#myInput').disableInput().addClass('otherClass');​
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the `.each()`, you can say `this.prop().addClass()`.

Comment: Don't you mean `$(this).prop('disabled', true);`  And anyway, wouldn't you want disableInput() to have a true/false parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable input elements using css properties. But you can improve your current coding like following

```
 $('#div_sercvice_detail :input').prop('disabled',true).addClass("disabled");
```