# How to disable elements of a jsp page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I have come up with a new query. The query goes like this,there is a popup window with various html elements, say radio buttons, check boxes, select lists and text field. I want that when i click an element, say a radio  button, the other elements should be disabled. And also, when I click an element, only selected elements should be disabled. How do I do this? I am using jQuery in jsp with stripes framework. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `class attribute` and have specified `CSS` for each class. To disable a specific element by clicking you can add `class` to those elements dynamically.If you have selected some elements(radio buttons, checkbox) you should add a class to element when you are selecting it.

[Disable html input element by applying custom css class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863499/disable-html-input-element-by-applying-custom-css-class)