# remove 'disabled' attr with pure css

Tags: css, button

I m know how to remove disabled with js, but is it possible to user only css?
I have 2 css classes. 1 for active buttons and 1 for disabled ones! If css can enable button. I could use just jquery's addClass and removeClass...

p.s. sorry for my super english skill.

Comment: You can't use pure css. Take a look at this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963099/how-do-i-disable-form-fields-using-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to remove any attribute with CSS. CSS cannot change the document tree at all. It can only specify suggestions on the *rendering* of a document.