# How to disable a part of HTML with media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to disable a part of my HTML, this code:

```
<div class="right">
```

with Media Queries when it gets to a certain screen size, but I'm not sure how to do it. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable form fields using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963099/how-do-i-disable-form-fields-using-css)

Comment: You can't "disabled" does not apply to divs, so that won't work for a start. What you can do is hide the element with `display:none`

Comment: It worked, but not the way, I needed it too. Is there a way to put a <div class="left"> to override the previously mentioned HTML when the screen size is 600px only?

Comment: You can't "override" with CSS, only style, including hiding and showing. Perhaps provide a more complete example of what you are trying to  achieve. At the moment your question is a little vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by disable you mean "disappear". Then you can use media queries to make that happen by setting the `display` property to `none`. Like this:

```css
/* A bit of color  */

.right {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: crimson;
}


/* Hide the <div> with class "right" when the screen width is 600 pixels or lower */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .right {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="right"></div>
```

Tip: Click "Run code snippet", then click "full page" and resize the screen of the browser until it disappears.

Learn more about media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).